# How to search Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum for words?

Tags: text-corpus, inscription, study-strategies, corpus-inscriptionum-latinarum

*Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum* (CIL) is a large corpus of Latin inscriptions.
The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_Inscriptionum_Latinarum) contains some links, but none of the tools linked there seem to allow me to make a text search.
For example, I might want to search for all inscriptions containing the word *senatus* spelled out in full or those containing the name *Agrippa*.
Is there a way to do this?
An advanced search tool is not necessary; it would be enough to have a sufficiently large chunk of the corpus in searchable form.
I feel that I must be missing something obvious, but I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Perhaps http://db.edcs.eu/epigr/epi.php?s_sprache=en (publication: CIL)?

Comment: @AlexB. That looks very promising after a quick trial! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Did you just create two tags for that? Hahaha

Comment: @Rafael I did, and I synonymized them immediately. I thought it would make future use easier. We haven't had many inscription questions yet, but I hope there will be more.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta I don't believe that it's possible to search yet, but digitization seems to be under development. This might help in assessing the situation: http://arachne.uni-koeln.de/drupal/?q=en/node/291

Answer (score 2):

[Hathi Trust](https://www.hathitrust.org/) is a large database of digitilised texts from universities all over the world (kind of an academic version of archive.org). Everything (as far as I know) is searchable. For "*Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum*", [there are many results](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?field1=ocr;q1=Corpus%20Inscriptionum%20Latinarum;a=srchls;lmt=ft). The first page shows volume 1, 2, 3, 5 and 7.