# How can I use Perseus for Boolean searches?

Tags: text-corpus, research

## Background and question

Encouraged by Joonas Ilmavirta in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58878511#58878511), as ‘Corpus tool questions are a useful thing to have for reference’, I boldly go forth asking this publicly: **Does anyone know how to do a Boolean [search on Perseus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/search)?** In my case, I would like to search:

```
( (suicide OR suicidal) OR ((kill OR destroy OR end) AND self) )
```

This I would then compare to those documents mentioning the same in Latin/Greek, to find which words were used for suicide. General tips on doing advanced searches in Perseus (or for that matter: similar platforms), will also be very welcome.

## Notes

### Of relevance

- [How to search Corpus Inscriptionum Latinarum for words?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/how-to-search-corpus-inscriptionum-latinarum-for-words?rq=1)
- [What are good sources to Antonine Law?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17082/what-are-good-sources-to-antonine-law)

Comment: The search form you linked to clearly just doesn't have this functionality. If you really want this, then you can always download their data and write your own offline search scripts. I've done this. Their file formats are somewhat of a pain to work with, and their licensing info is not as clear and consistent as one could wish.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure you can do what you want. Try the Loeb site instead for English translations.

Comment: @cmw: For the treebank, the license is CC-BY-SA, which is the same as wikipedia. See https://github.com/PerseusDL/treebank_data/issues/29

Comment: I sometimes Google the Perseus site: you won't get complete results, but you can use some Google logic.